# AssetFileDescriptor and Media Player #ISUESS

Tags: java, android

I m trying to play song by clicking a button in my application. There are two buttons in the application. Each button can play a different song. I allocated all those songs in Assets folder. There are total of two songs in the folder of Assets now.

```
public class AudioCollective implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, OnCompletionListener{
    static String TAG = "AudioCollective====>";
    Context mContext;
    MediaPlayer mPlayer;
    ArrayList<AssetFileDescriptor> array;

    public AudioCollective(Context theContext){
        mContext = theContext;

    }

    public void addSound(int SoundID){
        array = new ArrayList<AssetFileDescriptor>();
        AssetFileDescriptor afd = mContext.getResources().openRawResourceFd(SoundID);
        array.add(afd);
    }


    public void playSound() {

       for (int i =0; i<array.size();i++) {
           Log.i(TAG,"preparing audio " + array.get(i) );
            mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
           try {
               mPlayer.setDataSource(array.get(i).getFileDescriptor());
           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           try {
               mPlayer.prepare();
           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
           mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
       }


    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        if (mPlayer != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "releasing audio  now");
            mPlayer.release();
            mPlayer = null;
            mediaPlayer.release();
            //mediaPlayer = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        Log.i(TAG, "playing audio  now");
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
}
```

meanwhile in my MainActivity :

```
AudioCollective ac = new AudioCollective();
ac.addSounds(R.raw.na);
playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
               ac.playSound();
            }
        });
```

So, the problem is every time I clicked the button, the application play the two songs together instead of playing the required song. anyone can tell me why would this be happen?

Answer (score 0):

> Yes it because you are playing both of them at same in for loop.

Update your `playSound()` method pass value in it as argument.

To play first song pass 0 , To play second song pass 1 .

`playSound(0)` `playSound(1)`

```
     public void playSound(int pos) {

           Log.i(TAG,"preparing audio " + array.get(pos) );
            mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
           try {
               mPlayer.setDataSource(array.get(pos).getFileDescriptor());
           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           try {
               mPlayer.prepare();
           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
           mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
       }
    }
```

Comment: Vote up too if it helps happy coding :)

Comment: Hi there, I tried to remove the for..loop and the array, but the result is still the same, which means it play all the song in the Assets folder regardless of how many of them..